# Background-image not visible

Tags: html, css

I'm a very newbie to `CSS/HTML` and I can't seem to fix an issue I have.
This is the website I'm developing http://sahsahashas.tk
Now, when I preview website over Dreamweaver in chrome this is how navigation bar looks (the way its supposed to)
[http://i.imgur.com/4dw1j6K.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/4dw1j6K.jpg) (it is actually a picture, not a background color :)).

[image]

I know it looks almost the same but it really annoys me. Also, I know my CSS code is a mess but again, I'm a newbie.

```
.navbar {
    width: 708px;
    height: 61px;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(navbarr.jpg);
    font: normal normal 700 1em/4em Arial,sans-serif;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Show you HTML and CSS used for background-image

Comment: Please share the HTML + CSS code.

Comment: The community is going to chew you and use your bones as toothpick if you don't show effort to fix the problem yourself and if post code that you think is responsible for your woes.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand why its different when i preview it in dreamweaver and when i upload files on host.

Comment: @qualebs Someone has chewed him!! He has disappears from the site.

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo: `background: url(navbarr.jpg);` should be `navbar.jpg` or your image navbarr.jpg doesn't exist on the server. There is an image called navbar.jpg. Hope this helps.

Look at css in my firebug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iKsC.png

Comment: I think this is the solution. Some Webservers are configured in such a way, that they will send files with typo in the filename correctly, while the local file system doesn't. I think the apache module is this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html

Answer (score 1):

to specify the image as background you should not use only **background**,

I will suggest you to specify the **background-image** attribute and image name with valid path should in single(or double) quoted..

```
background-image: url('navbarr.jpg');
```